# Windows Phone 8 equivalent to Androids alert dialog?

Tags: list, windows-phone-8, popup, android-alertdialog, isolatedstorage

In an Android project I have this kind of alert dialog:

[image: Android Alert Dialog]

I want to replicate this in Windows Phone 8, however I haven't been able to find a suitable plugin/widget to do so. The list itself is populated by SharedPreferences.

My plan for Windows 8 was to use Isolated Storage Files to grab the required entries, is this the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<clippy>`It looks like you want to display a list to the user and allow them to pick an option `</clippy>`

If that is the case then you can use the ListPicker from the WP Toolkit. Install the nuget pack and use as such:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker FullModeHeader="CHOOSE LOCATION" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}">
     <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,20" TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}">
                         <Run Text="{Binding Description}" />
                         <Run Text="-" />
                         <Run Text="{Binding Quality}" />
                    </TextBlock >
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Comment: And the list will appear as a pop up without changing page/activity?

Comment: Correct. The sample above will display as a combobox/button. When the user taps it, it opens full screen to give the users a choice. You will need to subscribe to the SelectedItemChanged (or something similar) event

Comment: Thanks @Shawn I will give that a go. As for where the picker gets the list of items to display, is this a straight forward process? As I mentioned I'm thinking about creating a text file and storing comma delimited lines for each entry and only want to use the first parameter from each line as the list entry? if that makes sense....maybe another question should be posted by me regarding this.

Comment: In the sample I gave the items it displays are bound to some Cities` collection that your data is binding to. This collection would hold a `City` with properties `Description` and `Quality`. This is just an example. If the data is static, you could put them in a text file or put them directly into the xaml. The ListPicker accepts content directly in the element. If you go this route, remove the ItemsSource binding